# Eclipse can't read text file in src folder

Tags: java, java-io

I am implementing a Branch Predictor for one of my classes and I am trying to read files from my src folder in Eclipse but for some reason it is not able to open the files. I have done this before with the exact same process so I'm not sure what is different.

traceFile is set from the command line and if I print "input", it will print out the correct file path and I have confirmed it is there manually.

```
ClassLoader loader = BiModalPredictor.class.getClassLoader();
File input = new File(loader.getResource(traceFile).getFile());
Scanner fin = new Scanner(input);
```

Is there any insight as to why this might be happening?  I've tried restarting Eclipse, refreshing the files, and I've also tested it on another program which worked.  No idea why it can't find ***this*** file.

Comment: You src folder will not be on your class path.  Maybe move to `resources` folder which needs to be part of your class path - see maven

Comment: @scarywombat, I literally have another project with the exact same setup that works though. What would make the difference here?

Comment: here is a link to the code segment in the other project [link](http://prntscr.com/rpt9ir) and the files in the folder [link](http://prntscr.com/rpta1v)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Resources on the classpath, i.e. available through the classloaders [`getResource`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/ClassLoader.html#getResource-java.lang.String-) method, will not be files on the file system when your application is deployed as a jar file, or deployed in general. Do not use `File` with such resources, instead use [`getResourceAsStream`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/ClassLoader.html#getResourceAsStream-java.lang.String-) to access the resource content.

Besides, your code is wrong. `getResource()` returns a [`URL`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/net/URL.html). If you want a `File` object from a `URL`, you should use [`new File(uri)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/io/File.html#File-java.net.URI-), where the [`URI`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/net/URI.html) is obtained by calling [`url.toURI()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/net/URL.html#toURI--).

```
File input = new File(loader.getResource(traceFile).toURI());
```